# View all excluded files and folders in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

When i publish my application, there are some files not getting published. I know it is because those files are excluded from the solution. But the problem is i have to open all folders and sub folders recursively to find out out any file is excluded or not. This is really a pain for me.

Do any how visual studio provides option to list only the excluded files and folders?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a tool for this, but

Depend on your `.csproj` file format version, you can see a list of all the files that included or not included in your project (but not both).

The `.csproj` file is the file that describe your project, and located in the root project folder.

#### With the new format of `.csproj` (2017)

You can open this file by right-clicking on the project in Visual Studio and selecting **Edit the csproj file**.

In the file you can see files that marked as **Exclude**. These files will not be in the project.

#### With the old `.csproj` format

Open the `.csproj` file from the File Explorer, by any text files editor, and see all the files that **included** in this project.

---

Now, write a script for parse this files and comparing to the directory structure, and share this script with us as open source.